# Does the cold affect electrical conduction?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, temperature, electrical-resistance

Disclaimer: I'm not experienced in many phyiscal nor electrical terms and I have no idea where to ask this question elsewhere. I'd be open for a move request if needed.
Today when using public transport in switzerland I noticed something odd. All trians emitted a lot of sparks where they met the electrical supply line. Seen in different train stations on different trains.
[image]
(Image not from today, just as example)
I never noticed even in rain. The only difference from other days was the temperature.

> Time / Date: 7:15 - 7:40, January 16th 
> Sky: Still dark, not cloudy
>  Temperature: -2°C
> Humidity: 92%
>  Last snow / rain: The day before yesterday

Can these conditions cause an entire train network to emit sparks? If so why? Is there another possible explinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swiss Federal Railways explained that very same phenomenon [in a (German) newspaper article from 2013](https://www.srf.ch/sendungen/kassensturz-espresso/services/interaktiv/aha/darum-blitzt-es-ueber-der-lok).

The basic idea is that the cold weather leads to a thin layer of ice forming on the overhead wires. [The Swiss rail electrification system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_railway_electrification_systems) works with a voltage $15kV$, which is easily enough to lead to an electric arc between the engine collector and the wires.

On a side note, looking at the arcs directly is not advisable, due to the high light intensity. [This effect was (still is) used for movie projectors and high intensity searchlights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_lamp).

Comment: As an additional warning, the arcs are likely to contain UV radiation which can damage the eyes.